# Firebase sendScreen deobfuscation

Tags: android, firebase, proguard, firebase-analytics

I just integrated firebase analytics to my android app, and its looks like this:

```
FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(activity);

analytics.setCurrentScreen(activity, this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Screen name :" this.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

I have added this part of code to onResume() of my BaseFragment. So this all looks good on debug builds [Debug analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhM9W.png)

But when I change build type to release with

`minifyEnabled true`

all I see in firebase console is [Release analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkZVP.png) (there are only obfuscated file names)

Here is part of my ProGuard file 
[ProGuard rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNb35.png)

Maybe somebody can help me?

Comment: You can extend proguard rules to keep class names for all Activity/Fragment classes. For example:
`-keepnames class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment`